# Angular build result destroys html entities, how to prevent this from happening

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Currently using Angular 4+ and recently found a problem. When using an html entity in development mode and doing `npm start` the respective symbol shows up correctly. However, when I build the app and open it, the html entity gets converted to something else, essentially breaking the entity completely.

The entity is the down triangle ▼ or `&#9660;` but in the built app the resulting entity becomes this piece of html code `â–¼`. It is being placed directly inside the template of a component, there are no methods associated with it, it is as if it was written in the html file.

I have tried to find a way to prevent this from happening but the Angular documentation is an absolute nightmare when trying to find a solution for this and due to the terrible fragmented documentation related to each version on the web I was not able to find anything that allowed me to fix this problem.

How can I keep the html entities intact when I build the angular app?

Comment: which tool r you  using for build your project? angular-cli? gulp?

Comment: @happyZZR1400 I am using the AOT compiler, following the instructions located here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out why this is happening and it has nothing to do with Angular. The local server that I am using is serving the html with an encoding of ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8. Even after adding the meta tag inside the html file, the incorrect encoding prevails. The solution will be to make the server serve the document with the correct encoding.

EDIT: And yes, I made sure to check if the file itself was being saved with UTF-8 encoding.